# Match lucene entire field exact value

Tags: search, lucene, phrase

I'm  creating a Lucene 4.10.3  index.

I am using he StandardAnalyzer.

```
    String indexpath="C:\\TEMP";
    IndexWriterConfig iwc=newIndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_3,new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET)); 
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexpath));          
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);   
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "ANDHRA",Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "ANDHRA PRADESH",Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "ASSAM AND NAGALAND",Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "ASSAM",Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "PUNJAB",Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("city", "PUNJAB AND HARYANA",Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

when I try to search in lucene index using phrase query

for example

```
 try {
        QueryBuilder build=new QueryBuilder(new KeywordAnalyzer());
        Query q1=build.createPhraseQuery("city","ANDHRA");      
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:\\TEMP"));
        DirectoryReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);    
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        ScoreDoc hits[] = searcher.search(q1,10).scoreDocs;
        Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("city");
        for (int i=0; i < hits.length; i++) {
            Document document = indexReader.document(hits[i].doc,set);
            System.out.println(document.get("city"));
        }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

we get result as follow-

ANDHRA

ANDHRA PRADESH

When I am searching for "ANDHRA" how to get only "ANDHRA"  result,
not "ANDHRA PRADESH", how to match entire field value in lucene by using StandardAnalyzer?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to match the exact, unmodified and untokenized, value of the field, you shouldn't be analyzing it at all.  Simply use a `StringField` instead of `TextField`.

If you want some analysis (ie. lowercasing, or some such), but without tokenizing, you can use [`KeywordTokenizer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordTokenizer.html) in your `Analyzer` implementation for that.

If you are using a `QueryParser` to create your queries, be aware of how the the parser uses spaces to separate query clauses.  You may find it necessary to write queries like:  `city:ANDHRA\ PRADESH` (I do *not* believe `QueryParser.escape` will do this for you).